# Rails model foreign key not working when specifying explicitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `User` model and a `Message` model. My `message` table has the columns `created_for`, and `created_by` and these are both foreign keys to the `User` table.

I'm currently getting this error message:

`undefined method`created_for_id' for #`

How can I get this to work without having to change my columns to `created_for_id` and `created_by_id`?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :message
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

    #belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "User" # Basically tell rails that created_by is a FK to the users table
    belongs_to :created_for, :class_name => "User"  # Basically tell rails that created_for is a FK to the users table

    attr_accessible :created_by, :created_for, :message

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the foreign key for the belongs_to via:

```
belongs_to :created_for, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :created_for
```

I suspect you are going to run into an issue having the relation name and foreign key attribute sharing a name. Here is the [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) documentation, scroll down to the "Options"

Comment: I added the foreign_key and i get this error: `User(#70281925609240) expected, got String(#70281918088560)`. The line that throws the error is: `@message = Message.new(params[:message])` and here's the params `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EYvFRZkOlK0rB5Dvflfa8iN47rZUorPle3usdaSRobk=", "message"=>{"created_for"=>"1", "message"=>"asdf"}, "button"=>"", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"messages"}`

Comment: It has to be because the relation and the foreign key have the same name. I would change the name of one of them, as it's only going to cause problems, maybe call the relation `for` instead of `created_for`

Comment: So if changed the column names to `for` and `by`, what would the foreign_key need to be? I guess i don't understand how changing `for` and `by` would make anything different.

Comment: If the column was for, your relation would be defined like this `belongs_to :created_for, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'for'` when you had both the relation and the column sharing a name, when you set the foreign key on the model, it was doing a check to make sure it was the type specified in the belongs_to

Comment: I just changed `belongs_to :for`. I used to think that a `belongs_to` had to be the label of your column.